# How can I connect my Casio keyboard to my pc?

Tags: audio-interfaces, keyboard

Basically, I am wondering whether I can connect my keyboard to my pc or not. I don't know if it is possible and I am very, very new to this community. I very recently purchased an audio interface (U-Phoria UMC22). I currently use the Mic/Line 1 port for my microphone. I was thinking that I could connect my keyboard via the Inst 2 port. My keyboard is a Casio CTK-496. This keyboard is roughly 15 years old. I searched for the manual online and I managed to find it. This page is the only one, I think, that shows the I/O on the back and explains it. I have no idea what any of this means. If I could connect my keyboard, what cables do I need? Any help is appreciated! Thank You in advance. [image]

Answer (score 2):

sure, you can totally connect the Casio to the interface.

...one side of it at least.

You need a cable that is stereo at the Casio end and dual mono 1/4" at the interface end...I can't tell if the output jack on the keyboard is 1/8" or 1/4", but it's definitely stereo.

And you'll be able to plug in one channel of the Casio to the interface. 
Left or Right, the choice is yours.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I need a stereo cable that splits into 2 mono cables. Does that mean I have to plug it into both the Mic/Line 1 and Inst 2? And if I connect only right or left, how does that affect the audio. Will you only be able to hear it one side of headphones. Why can't I just use a stereo cable at the Casio end and another stereo cable at the interface end? Sorry for all these questions, I still trying to learn.

Comment: ok...think this through.  your casio has a single stereo output. your interface has two mono inputs. so, yes, you need a "stereo cable that splits to two mono cables".  The reason you can't use "a stereo cable at the Casio end and another stereo cable at the interface end" ought to be extremely clear, but it's because the interface does not have stereo inputs.

Comment: You mentioned that my interface has two mono inputs, does that mean I have to plug in the dual-mono outputs to both the mono inputs. In your first answer you said I can only plug in either the left or the right, but I was still confused.

Comment: Yes, that's because in your question you state that you use input 1 for the microphone. That leaves one available input, and in your question you state you were thinking you could connect the keyboard to input 2..the answer is of course yes, with the cable described, you can connect either the left or right side of the keyboard to the #2 input of the interface. The question has been clearly answered, and all of the information you need is there.